# Syslinux gives error: ata 10: Softreset failed (1st FIS failed)

Tags: arch-linux, boot, syslinux

I recently installed arch on my desktop, and I get the error in the title twice per boot, without the [] and preceded by what I assume is a timestamp: [12.xxxxxxx] on the first and [22.xxxxxx] on the second.

I have 1 SSD, 1 1TB HDD and two old laptop drives connected. The SSD still has my windows partitions on it (sdb1 and sdb2, arch is sdb3). I mount sdb3 as root and sda1 (the 1tb) in /media/HDD/ on boot.

I'm assuming the error has something to do with the laptop drives being old and not supporting some feature, but how do I go about identifying the problem drive and fixing this?